# After changing database to single user - I can't access it

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I need to do some maintenance work on a database.

After changing it to single user mode:

> ALTER DATABASE SOPHOS50 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

I loose connection to it (even from the Management Studio)

[image]

I tried to check who has access to it with the stored procedure: `sp_who2`

And there is only one entry in the report:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single user mode is named possibly slightly incorrectly, it doesn't mean only 1 user can log in, it means there can be only 1 single connection to the database.

As it is in single user mode, you can only have one connection open to the database, SSMS creates multiple connections, each query window creates one and then the object explorer will create more each time you try and look at properties etc.

What has likely happened is that either your original query window where you ran the alter database statement has kept hold of the single connection and so when you try and use object explorer, there are no more connections available to the database so you get the error you see there, or something else like a service has started and grabbed the single connection from you before you got a chance.

Make sure to shut down any services and query windows/applications that may be grabbing the single connection and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly disable your SQL server agent then right click on your database then click on new query then use query of

Alter database database_name
Set Multi_user

Execute this query
Refresh your database